# How to dynamically read out a widget state in Ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, widget, ipywidgets

Is there a way to create a widget in an Ipython notebook and to read out the state of this widget at a different position in the code?

I tried using

```py
from ipywidgets import interact

def f(x):
 pass

interact(f,x=True)
```

As a result, `f(x)` is executed when I klick the generated checkmark. This is not what I need. Instead, I would like to read out the state of the ckeckmark at a different position in the code. What is the best way to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created the widget `x`, then get `x.value` where you need it in the code. For a toggle widget this should return a boolean.